# Reaction speed timer

Tags: javascript, timer

Im making a reaction speed game. But without much succes.
You can find it on:
http://jdopperen.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/pws/ 
But I dont know how to make a timer for it?
This is what i have now:

```
    <div class="container mainmain">
    <h1>
      Je speelt nu.
    </h1>
        <script>
          var start;
          var end;
          var n;

          $( ".bodym" ).click(function() {
              setInterval(function(){
                  $( ".circle2" ).css( "fill", "yellow" ); 
                  start = new Date().getTime();
              }, 3000, 14000);

              $(".circle2").click(function(){
                  n = start.getTime();
                  document.write(n);
              });
          });;
    </script>
    <div class="circle2">
        <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Ofcourse i see it incomplete, but i don't know what to add to start time and stop it when the circle changes to yellow. + If they click before the circle turned yellow it shouldn't give a time but an error.
If you have any questions relating to my code please ask.

PS. Sorry for my bad english grammer.

Comment: explain the process of your game? number each step and what its supposed to do and its goal

Answer (score 0):

I just made https://jsfiddle.net/36qd9g1q/1/ , you can check it out, and use some of it for your needs. Point of the game is - click start button, it will wait 5 seconds, and then will start the timer. You must press red block in the middle as soon as it turns green. After that, it adds score to the table, and you can play again by clicking button again. I made no validation, no fancy stuff, only basic stuff, to bring you on some tracks.

Game starts with this:

```
$("#start").click(function(){
  setTimeout( // in 5000 ms btn will be green
    function() {
      startTime = new Date(); // register current time
      timerVar = setInterval(countTimer, 1); // call this every 1 ms to update UI with timer
      $("#target").css("background-color", "green"); //make it green
    }, 5000);
});
```

And the game ends here:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  $("#target").css("background-color", "yellow"); //resets color
  $("#scores").append($("<tr>").append($("<td>").html($("#timer").html()))); // inserts record into table
  $("#timer").empty(); // clears timer in UI
  clearInterval(timerVar); // stops timer
});
```